# How to solve shared library error "loadLib error" with shared libararies in C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling, shared-libraries

I am using a `.dll` in C# which uses shared libraries, but when I want to use that shared library, I get this error:

> Exception of type: OPTION_INVALID in file "../../../src/Algorithm/IpAlgBuilder.cpp" at line 295:
> Exception message: Selected linear solver MA57 not available.
> Tried to obtain MA57 from shared library "libhsl.dll", but the following error occurred:
> loadLib error: Do not know how to handle shared libraries on this operating system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbJ9v.png)

Why does this happen and what should I do ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Which compiler?

Comment: Hi,
I am using Windows 10x64bit and my C# compiler is
 Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.4.1-beta4-19614-01 (16504609)
and I have also gcc 10.2.0 and g++ 10.2.0 , installed